# How do I fix links in different directories when using htaccess and RewriteRules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My folder structure is something like this:

```
.htaccess
index.php
topics.php
create.php
register.php
templates/
    frontpage.php
    topics.php
    create.php
    register.php
    includes/
        header.php
        footer.php
```

When I'm on `index.php` the links in header and footer work perfect. To clean the URLs, I created a `.htaccess` file that looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

# Manually rewriting rules for pages to preserve user profile pages - need to fix later
RewriteRule  ^about$         about.php         [NC,L]   # take out .php extention
RewriteRule  ^register$      register.php      [NC,L]   # take out .php extention
RewriteRule  ^create$        create.php    [NC,L]   # take out .php extention 

# Rewrite topic page
RewriteRule  ^topics/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    topics.php?category=$1    [NC,L]

# Rewrite user profile pages to MyMentor.Codes/username
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    user.php?username=$1    [NC,L]
```

My links in `header.php` look like this:

```
<a href="about"></a>
<a href="register"></a>
<a href="create"></a>
<a href="find-mentor"></a>
```

And the topics link in `footer.php` loos like this:

```
<a href="topics/category/<?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
```

Now let's say I'm at the page `website.com/topics.php?category=programs`
My `.htaccess` page changes it to `website.com/topics/category/programs` just as it should.

However, now that I'm at `website.com/topics/category/programs` all of my links in header go to `website.com/topics/category/index.php` (or whatever link it would be), and the topics link in the footer goes to `website.com/topics/category/topics/category/programs`

Inside header, I can change the links to `<a href="../../myLink">`, and that will fix the links for `topics.php`, but obviously this messes up the links when I'm on any of the controller pages on the same level as `index.php`

And same goes for the footer, I could change it to `<a href="<?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>` which fixes the link when inside topics.php, but again when I'm on the root directory like `index.php` or another page on that level, the link goes to `website.com/programs` and acts as if it's one of my user profile pages (see `.htaccess`)

How can I fix these links or my `.htaccess` page so I don't have to have a separate header and footer for each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added this in to my website (into a `config.php` page):

```
define ('BASE_URI', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/myWebsite/');
```

Then before all my links, I just added `<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your links with a `/`. For instance change

```
<a href="about"></a>
```

To

```
<a href="/about"></a>
```

The problem you face is that when the browser sees just `"about"` it thinks you want that path relative to the current location, so it asks the server for the wrong location. Instead you want to use the full path as you expect `.htaccess` to see it

In response to your comment below: If you want `.htaccess` to prepend all paths with `website/`, Add the 2nd rule below when you enable mod rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on   <- you should already have this
RewriteBase '/website/'
```

And move the `.htaccess` one level up, so it's inside the `website/` directory.

The solution above is easy but I wouldn't do it on my own machine. A solution that takes slightly more work but has the advantage of keeping all your files inside `website/` is to edit the Apache setting (assuming you use Apache) that determines your website's root directory.  This is currently misconfigured for your localhost site.

Your current setting is `htdocs/`. That's why the browser is navigating to `localhost/thisPage`.  What you want is each site to have its own root folder, so we need to change the setting to `htdocs/website/`

This is done in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.  Look for the `VirtualHost` section that has to do with your current site and change `DocumentRoot` so it looks similar to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/htdocs/website"
```

You'll need to restart the webserver for changes to take effect. Once they do, you can remove the `RewriteBase` we setup earlier or just set it to `/`

Comment: I'm testing on localhost. When I edited all my links to add the `/` in front, all pages now direct to `localhost/thisPage` instead of `/localhost/website/thisPage`

Comment: With `Rewrite Base '/website/'` I get a server error 500. When I change it to `RewriteBase '/website/'` and leave the `/` before my links, they still go to `localhost/thisPage`

Comment: @amallard Please rephrase your last comment. I don't understand.  You said `/website/` in your rewrite base gives you `500 error`. Then you said that if you change it to `/website/` it still goes to `localhost/thisPage`. How could both statements be true?

Comment: I was referring to the space between `Rewrite` and `Base` in your answer. I assume it was just a typo and you meant `RewriteBase` which is why I put both. Sorry if that was unnecessary and just assumed, I'm new to `.htaccess`

Comment: @amallard You're right (was a typo). Take another look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Move it so it's in the `htdocs` folder? Won't this affect all my other websites in localhost (and therefore on my remote server too?)

Comment: `htdocs` is the directory above `website`, but I have `website2` in there too. What would I do if I wanted a separate `.htaccess` for each website? This is the same as I have it on my hosting account too.

Comment: @amallard you read my mind. I was expanding while you asked your last 2 Qs. take another look.